# SQL: doing math on COUNT column just carried over

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

```
SELECT January.customer_id AS Jancust_id, 
COUNT( DISTINCT January.customer_id ) AS Jan_orig_cust,
COUNT (DISTINCT payments.customer_id) as Jan_retain_cust,
Jan_retain_cust/ 1533 AS CAC_referral
FROM January_Cohort January
LEFT JOIN telemon_payments_data payments
ON January.customer_id = payments.customer_id
WHERE January.acquisition_source = 'referral'
AND 
payments.payment_date BETWEEN '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-31'
```

Ok, can I not do math on a column in the same query that uses COUNT & was just brought over?  Error message below.

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DISTINCT payments.customer_id) as Jan_retain_cust,
>   Jan_retain_cust/ 1533 AS CAC_' at line 3"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `group by` clause. Also, you are trying to use alias `Jan_retain_cust` in expression in the same select which is *not* allowed. Just the replace the alias `Jan_retain_cust` with original expression i.e. `COUNT (DISTINCT payments.customer_id)`.

```
select January.customer_id as Jancust_id,
    COUNT(distinct January.customer_id) as Jan_orig_cust,
    COUNT(distinct payments.customer_id) as Jan_retain_cust,
    COUNT(distinct payments.customer_id) / 1533 as CAC_referral
from January_Cohort January
left join telemon_payments_data payments on January.customer_id = payments.customer_id
where January.acquisition_source = 'referral'
    and payments.payment_date between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-31'
group by January.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** refer alias column in same query.

```
SELECT January.customer_id AS Jancust_id, 
COUNT( DISTINCT January.customer_id ) AS Jan_orig_cust,
COUNT (DISTINCT payments.customer_id) as Jan_retain_cust,
Jan_retain_cust/ 1533 AS CAC_referral    <--- You can not do.
FROM January_Cohort January
LEFT JOIN telemon_payments_data payments
ON January.customer_id = payments.customer_id
WHERE January.acquisition_source = 'referral'
AND 
payments.payment_date BETWEEN '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-31'
```

Also, as pointed by @GurV, you are also missing `group by` clause.

Comment: Thanks, so it is what I referenced above